# How to show 'loading' between MVC Views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a jquery-generated table full of data. In that table, one of the columns has a link (standard `<a href="">`) to another View (entirely separate controller). Clicking this link can, frequently, cause a long load time, as the View that is loading potentially has a massive amount of data to churn through before spewing its results onto the screen.

Is there a way, upon clicking one of those links, to get a 'loading spinner' until the new screen loads?

Again, this is a standard hyperlink (href) in a View that links to a completely separate View, separate controller.

Comment: If you are not using ajax to load your other view, then you cannot. If you are using ajax to load then you just need to put a spinner in the `div` before you load the html into it.

Comment: The views are entirely separate pages - two .aspx views. The second I click the link in, let's call it 'Page1.aspx', I'm not really _on_ Page1.aspx any more... even though it's sitting there in the browser. I'm actually on Page2.aspx, waiting for data. Sadly, the Browser doesn't know this.

Comment: For some of my sites where I am just concerned with showing the user a 'Please Wait' message until the next page loads I use the jQuery Block UI plugin. On the event of that link being clicked I just call the blockUI function to show the customized wait message. If you're interested I can throw something up in an answer to show more detail. Just an idea if that is all you are looking to do.

Comment: @BKirby Actually, that sounds brilliant. I'd be quite interested to see it.

Comment: I've only just noticed (because we don't actually USE it anywhere in the site, yet) that I have jquery.blockUI.js! So, I'm guessing your method would be something like having the href be `<a href="#" onClick="block('/myPage/' + variableId + )">Go To New Page</a>` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a sample from one of my sites with a submit button and simply blocking the UI on click. The image below shows what the user then sees. After the data is gathered the new page is then loaded and presented.

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="searchparty">

<script>
//submit search, display loading message
    $('input[type = submit]').click(function(){
        $.blockUI({ css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: .6
        } }); 
    });
</script>
```

[image: blockUI]

Comment: Using blockUI has been a lifeSaver! Thanks so much for pointing this out. I've already incorporated it into a couple pages this morning, and I'm quite enamoured with it. :)

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear! :)

Comment: I tried this. But "Loading please wait " text is not displaying @B Kirby

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following with Javascript events to show loading image while a page loads:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $(".loadingDiv-parent").fadeOut("slow");
});
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
  $(".loadingDiv-parent").fadeIn(50);
});
```

CSS to display image properly:

```
/*  LOADING SPINNER  */
.loadingDiv-parent {
   position: fixed;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 999998;       
}

.loadingDiv {
   position: fixed;
   text-align: center;
   top: 40%;
   left: 45%;
   z-index: 999999;
}

.loadingDiv .loading-image {
   display: block;
   margin: 25px 75px;
}
```

Then in the View:

```
<div class="loadingDiv-parent">
  <div class="loadingDiv">
    <div class="card border-success">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Loading ... Please Wait</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <i class="Your_icon loading-image" style="font-size:7em;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span id="panelclose_btn"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used a [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/)  icon to show as a loading spinner image.