# C# MVC is it Possible to Run a another Function after i Return the View without JS?

Tags: c#, web, model-view-controller

My page is called from another website that has a token in its URL parameters, I need to do some async work with this token, at the same time, I don't want my page to be blank while the server is doing the work (it might take 20 seconds).

My current setup:

First: My page is loaded with a spinner Please wait (Loading...) and my controller does not utilize the token received.

Second: The client sends the Token back to the server with JS AJAX.

Third: The server does the work with the token and displays a success or failure message.

Is it possible to do this without JS and somehow have a page displayed telling the user to wait while the server does its work on the token?

Comment: The short answer is no, not without using any JS if you want to let the user know the result. If that is not a requirement you could kick off a fire and forget async task before the action returns. Alternatively, you could put up the spinner from the calling page and let the new page load happen when the work is completed; but JS is still required, and this is really just talking about order. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490495/how-to-show-loading-between-mvc-views

Comment: The calling page is not on my site, so I can't control that.

Comment: Unfortunately, JS is a necessary evil to get work done from the client side of an MVC application. I've even gone so far as to replace most client side functionality of an MVC app with Angular for this reason. The issue is that to display a page to the client the Action must have already returned a View. If the action has already returned, it cannot return, redirect, etc. again. So you are left needing the client to in some way initiate the required action - enter JS. Perhaps if there is something about your JS you don't like you could share it and we could try to help rework it?

Comment: I don't want the token to be sent to me from the client, that's the only reason. What about WebSockets?

Comment: If you're really just trying to avoid sending the actual token back from the client for some reason (security concern?) you could cache the token in the session when the controller first receives it. Then the client just calls a ProcessToken action which retrieves the token from the cache and does its magic, returning a result to the client.